# What files to check into source control for sbt/activator project?

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

When using gradle/Java I know what to check in (gradle wrapper/gradle shell script) and what not to check in (.gradle) and instead have in my .gitignore.

What should one check in for a activator/sbt projects for Scala?

I see the following files in a recent project I created:

- activator (shell script)
- activator.bat
- activator-launch-1.2.12.jar
- build.sbt
- target (tree of files)
- project (tree of files)

I don't see any useful guides for this via a google search on on the sbt reference manual.

Ok, this might help a bit.  I decided to create a new project (using activator).  I did template = minimal-scala and project name minimal-scala.  It created the following files:

```
hostname:minimal-scala username$ find . -type f
./.gitignore
./activator
./activator-launch-1.2.12.jar
./activator.bat
./build.sbt
./LICENSE
./project/build.properties
./src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala
./src/test/scala/HelloSpec.scala

hostname:minimal-scala username$ cat .gitignore 
/RUNNING_PID
/logs/
/project/*-shim.sbt
/project/project/
/project/target/
/target/
```

I'm guessing this means, I should checkin the .gitignore as is, the src tree, build.sbt, project (everything but what was noted in .gitignore), activator jar and launching sh and bat files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, you should check in only those files which are absolutely necessary to build a project.

Build.sbt - necessary. You can't build the project without it.

project - project contains plugins and Build.scala files which are necessary. Check those in. It usualy contains the target folder which should not be checked in.

I use sbt for everything and eclipse as IDE. Others might use activator but it is not necessary. This is a personal preference which should not be part of your build.

It comes down to this basically, how much a new person needs to download before being productive. You check in activator which he might not even need.

Comment: Pretty close.  project also contains project and project/target, not just target. Will check if activator helps people.

Comment: I agree with this answer combined with the additional information I added in the original question.  I believe having activator there is good as well as people who don't have SBT installed can't get started otherwise.  It seems like activator adds the same benefit as gradle wrapper scripts in Java.

Comment: basically, just exclude target/ directories.  the actiavtor-launch.jar + scripts are like gradlew for sbt.

Answer (score 1):

I would check in all of the dirs/files above except for 'target'.  target is the end result of a
build.  In general, you want to check in files so that someone else can do a 'git clone'
and start working off that with minimal fuss.

Also by the way, don't check in things like passwords, aws keys, and the like :(